# PlotStyle not coloring individual points correctly

Tags: plotting, color

I am trying to create a 3D scatter plot, where each point is colored according to a fourth parameter (not corresponding to any of the values on the axes). To do this, I generated a list of colors, which I was going to map onto the set of points using the PlotStyle option. However, although I am correctly generating a list of colors (Which are different--I checked this!), all of my points are being assigned the same color.

I was hoping someone could help me out! I pasted my code below (I added it as an image so it would be easier to see the problem, but I can also paste the code if needed!).

[image]

Comment: Edit your question to include your code in a copy and pasteable form (`InputForm` in a code block) rather than an image -- particularly an image too small to be read.

Comment: Use `Graphics3D[{Point[listOfPoints, VertexColors -> listOfColors]}]`

Comment: Or wrap each point in its own list: ``ListPointPlot3D[Transpose@{First@WCParamDataFunction[]}, PlotStyle -> ...]``.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I'll move the answer here so it shows up as resolved!

Domen's suggestion to wrap each point in a list worked!

```
ListPointPlot3D[Transpose@{First@WCParamDataFunction[]}, PlotStyle -> ...]
```

I wonder why this is?

Comment: `ListPointPlot3D` uses one color for each data set, so you need to make each point its own data set.